# Restrict special character and number in java programming

Tags: java

I want to accept all languages characters but I do not want to accept special character and number. I have created db which is accepting all languages font. for this I am using below code ...

```
public static Boolean validateName(String name,CodeDescription codeDescription,BaseResponseDto baseDto) {
      Boolean flag = false;

     String expression= "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(['()+,\\-.=]+)";
      if(!name.matches(expression)){
          baseDto.code = codeDescription.code;
          baseDto.description = codeDescription.description;
          baseDto.status=false;
          flag=true;
      }
      return flag;
   }
```

Comment: ji when I am giving timil font name its not taking. Not only any language font is not taking accept english. But I have to restrict only special character and number apart from that all language font should be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Boolean validateName(String name,CodeDescription codeDescription,BaseResponseDto baseDto) {
  Boolean flag = false;

 String expression= "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(['()+,\\-.=]+)";
  if(!name.contains(expression)){
      baseDto.code = codeDescription.code;
      baseDto.description = codeDescription.description;
      baseDto.status=false;
      flag=true;
  }
  return flag;
```

}

try this ! it should work

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the problem is not the expression but rather the `if`.

```
if(!name.matches(expression)){ ... }
```

Checks if a name is not valid, but you are returning true, which leads to it being valid. If you use

```
if(name.matches(expression)){ ... }
```

It should work.